# Writing a comfortable pause/stop method for a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, java-threads

For a Thread subclass in Java I was trying to write a method `checkPauseAndStop()`, whose purpose was to be nice one-liner I could periodically call within the `run()` method to check whether there are pause/stop requests and to act accordingly.

While fully functional, stopping the thread is handled via `InterruptedException` which forces the run()-code to be in a try-catch and feels error-prone 
(as e.g. Thread.sleep() won't tell you anymore that it may throw such an Exception).

Is there any nice way that handles stopping the thread internally in the method without impeding on the run()-method?

Code sample:

```
public class SuspendableThread extends Thread
{
   private Semaphore lock = new Semaphore(1);
   public void checkPauseRequest() throws InterruptedException
    {
        if (isInterrupted())
            throw new InterruptedException();

        lock.acquire();
        lock.release();

    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        try
        {
            while (true)
            {
                // Do_stuff
                checkPauseRequest();
            }

        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Of cause, in this particular example, it isnt' necessary at all. For greater effect, imagine we'd have 50 or more consecutive blocks of

```
// Do_stuff
checkPauseRequest();
```

instead of just one.

Comment: `lock` needs to be accessible to some other thread so it can `acquire()` so this  thread will pause when it `acquire()`s.  A simple shared`AtomicBoolean shouldStop` might be enough to return without having to use InterruptedException.  Either way, you still have to decide where `checkPauseRequest()` should be placed within the loop.  Either 1 time or multiple times, whatever makes sense to be able pause/stop after some unit of work.

Comment: Consider using a `Semaphore` instead of using a `Lock`. The reason is, the _[principle of least astonishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_astonishment)_.  When other programmers see a `Lock`, they normally expect it to be used for mutual exclusion; but when they see a `Semaphore`, they expect it to be used for signalling between threads. If you use a `Lock` for signalling, it may give other programmers the impression that your coding style is "weird", and perhaps, not trustworthy.

Comment: @AndrewS I'm not really following your argumentation there. How does `AtomicBoolean` help here, besides being an alternative to `Semaphore`?

Comment: `AtomicBoolean` was an example to be able to gracefully exit the thread as opposed to catching `InterreuptedException` and returning from the catch.  `Semaphonre` would still be good to pause the thread.

Comment: @AndrewS I don't see however, how other than by using an exception, I can jump multiple scopes backwards (besides calling run once for every scope to exit)

Comment: What do you mean by _jump multiple scopes backwards_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would architect this using a `ScheduledExecutorService` (which you can create with `Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor`) and an `enum RunningState { RUNNING, PAUSED, STOPPED }`.

While the state is `RUNNING`, we keep scheduling delayed tasks (using `ScheduledExecutorService.schedule`). Each task checks to see if we are still `RUNNING`, and if so, enqueues a single loop iteration (using `ExecutorService.submit` or `Executor.execute`). Then it schedules a new delayed task for the next iteration (not unlike a `Timer`, which you could potentially use instead, at the expense of yet another thread).

If the state is `PAUSED`, we keep scheduling the delayed tasks to keep checking for the transition back into `RUNNING` state. But we don't schedule the work items for the actual loop iterations.

If the state is `STOPPED` then we stop scheduling any more delayed tasks.

The state variable can be stored in a simple `volatile` field, which could be static (if there is only one of these things) or could be wrapped up in an object which represents the "thread" (which isn't actually a single thread anymore, but can resemble one from the caller's perspective).

Comment: It's an interesting approach. Let's say I don' t have a few-line-loop, but a long list of distinct tasks over which I loop. To transform it to work with a scheduler, wouldn't I have to take each work unit, put it in a `Runnable`, and then execute it? If so, I fear it would fragment the purpose of the code too much

Comment: I don't know what your codebase looks like, but in my experience, making each unit of work a `Runnable` instance does not fragment the codebase, and instead often makes things more readable (and makes the context of each operation nicely contained in a single object). More importantly, it fits the `Executor` model better, and makes it easy to build other mechanisms like cancellation, awaiting results, and even parallelization, if that's suitable for your task. Generally: `Thread` is a low-level abstraction; use higher-level abstractions whenever possible.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to catch an interrupt sent to a thread, to perform a cleanup for eg., you cannot get around putting your whole run() code block in a try/catch exception block. The reason being that if your thread is performing any kind of inter-thread signalling, via a conditional variable or a semaphore for eg (Calling the `wait()` method), your run() code block will immediately throw an `InterruptedException`, if the interrupt status flag is set for the thread. However, if you want to proactively check the interrupt status of your thread, the easiest way to do that would be to spray a bunch of interrupt points, aka your `checkPause()` method, and put a sleep of few nano seconds (Your `sleep()` method will throw an InterruptedException if the interrupted flag is set). This achieve your goals without compromising too much on the thread performance.

Comment: In terms of effort to effect, this sounds really effective, if you only want a method to conveniently stop an interrupted thread.

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure that what you're trying to achieve really makes sense and doesn't fall into *let's reinvent the wheel* category. Making any general one-size-fits-all stop method isn't something trivial, although it looked so even to Java creators. That's why Thread.stop() method is deprecated. (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop()) (And Thread.destroy() wasn't actually implemented AFAICT.)

There's a very nice explanation available: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html.

Comment: The OP used the word, "stop", but `t.stop()` does something very different from what the OP asked for.  The thread on the receiving end of a `stop()` call has no say in the matter: Some other thread could call `t.stop()` at any time, and there's nothing thread `t` can do to clean up if it happened to be in the middle of breaking some important data structure. What the OP asked for, on the other hand, was a clean way for thread `t` to check, _at safe points_, whether it has been asked to pause or stop.

Comment: @besmirched And that's why I included a link to a tutorial describing how to use interrupt. ;-)
While not referring strictly to this very question, I often see people trying to implement "threading model living in their mind" in Java, instead of using the threading model actually *existing* in Java. Of course, I was also implementing semaphores using Java's monitors for academic purposes but that's not quite how ('low level') threads should be used. Last, but not lest, this is also a reference for folks hitting this page from search engines in the future.

Comment: Your assumptions are probably spot on.  Still, a failed try is most often very educational

Comment: @Sudix But of course! There's no better way to learn programming IMHO than experimenting. Trouble is a lot of people are using SO as blind copy-paste source to create their production-grade applications... ;-)